# How do I partition my harddrive?

Tags: resize

[gpart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaxam.png)

How do i resize this and make a new 200GB partition here?

Comment: Just click and drag it to the size you want after selecting partition and clicking on Parttition/resize in the Menu.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff itried ti do so.but linux is installed on that partition,so i couldn't unmount it/

Comment: Oh...Use a live Gparted CD. Then you can do it. http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information available on the gparted.org site, including a manual page which has this [section](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition) on resizing a partition.

It states that you start by selecting some partition space, then it looks like you'll get an option to resize or move that petition.

I reckon go ahead and have a read of the manual on this one, it looks like it has everything you'd need.